# Why is the range of double precision variable NA in R and how do I change it to integer?

Tags: r

I uploaded a data frame into R and R is identifying some of my variables as "integer" (which is correct) and others as "double". 
When I look at my data frame, the correct numbers are within "double" columns and when I bring my cursor over the variable names it is showing that the "double" variables are numeric and it's showing me the correct range.

However, when I type in:

```
range(df$double_variable)
```

I get:

```
[1] NA NA
```

I need to create a variable based on an equation including both the numeric value of my "double" variables and my "integer" variables... This code is running just fine, but the values for this variable are off because it's reading all of my "double" variables as NA...

I tried converting the "double" variables as integers:

```
df$double_variable <- as.integer(df$double_variable)
```

and in doing so, I received the following warning message:

```
NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

And when looking at the range of this now integer variable, I again got:

```
[1] NA NA
```

Any ideas on what I should try next?

Comment: Your data frame might contain missing values. Check @joran comment to compute the range after removing them. You might want to check why some values are missing and if this is OK.

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example ?

Comment: Thank you Joran & Samuel, specifying that there are missing values in my code gave me the correct range.